# How to copy multiple files to a different folder removing some characters on each one | unix korn shell

Tags: shell, unix, cp

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to copy multiple files to a folder and changing the name or pattern that the files has. this is the example:

I have files with this pattern:

```
file1_100.csv.12345
file2_100.csv.12345
```

I want to copy those files to another folder without loop removing ".12345" as follow:

```
file1_100.csv
file2_100.csv
```

I just figured out that you can do this:

```
ls -l file* | awk -F. '{print $1 "." $2}'
```

and with that you can get the output:

```
file1_100.csv
file2_100.csv
```

could be possible to do something similar copying the files to another directory?

Answer (score 1):

```
   sed 's:\(regexp\):cp \1 dir_path/\1:g' | csh
```

## example

If you have files named: **file1 file2 ... fileN** and you want to copy them to a dirctory named **/home/kuku/** and you want to add a **prefix of temp** to each one of the files that all your files will be **temp_file1 temp_file2 ... temp_fileN**

```
    # Using list of files
     sed 's:\(file.*\):cp \1 home/kuku/temp_\1:g' file_list.txt| csh


    #for pipe files that end with .12345
       printf '%s\n' *.12345 | sed 's:\(.*\)\(.12345\):cp \1\2 home/kuku/\1\n:g' | csh
```

1) `printf '%s\n' *12345` get all files in local directory that end with 12345 string

2) us `sed` to print `cp file_name path/new_file_name`

3) Pipe strings to `csh` shell , exe line by line

Comment: I was wrong with OP needs, OP need to copy, not to move. You're right. I just corrected your `ls` parsing because it's a bad practice http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and +1 for better understanding :)